# How to add List as value in Hashtable

Tags: vb.net, list, hashtable

In vb.net If I have `HashTable`,`key` is integer and the value is a `list of integers`, how to append integers to the value of a given key, 
I have tried it but each time I found the integer last added only, (the list only has the last item added).

Here is my code , where `dt` is `DataTable` object

```
Dim dt = report.getEvaluationReportByObjectiveGroupId(29)
Dim data As New Hashtable()
Dim dataEntry As DictionaryEntry

Dim res As String
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim strYear = row.Item("Year")
    Dim strData = row.Item("EmpCount")


    If data.ContainsKey(strYear) Then
        Dim newCountArr As List(Of Int32) = DirectCast(data(strYear), List(Of Int32))
        '   newCountArr.AddRange(data(strYear))
        newCountArr.Add(strData)
        '  data.Remove(strYear)
        ' data.Add(strYear, newCountArr)
    Else
        Dim countArr As New List(Of Integer)
        countArr.Add(strData)
        data.Add(strYear, countArr)
    End If

    ' data.Add(strYear, strData)
Next row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use the strongly typed [`Dictionary(Of Int32, List(Of Int32))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) instead, it works similar. But anyway, here's the [`HashTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) approach:

```
Dim table = New Hashtable
Dim list = New List(Of Int32)
For i = 1 To 999
    list.Add(i)
Next
table.Add(1, list)

' somewhere else you want to read the list for a given key (here 1) '
Dim list1 As List(Of Int32) = DirectCast(table(1), List(Of Int32))
list.Add(1000) ' add another integer to the end of the list '
' note: you don't need to add the list to the HashTable again '
```

**Edit**: Since you've posted your code, here's the corrected:

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim strYear = row.Field(Of Int32)("Year")
    Dim strData = row.Field(Of Int32)("EmpCount")
    Dim list As List(Of Int32)

    If data.ContainsKey(strYear) Then
        list = DirectCast(data(strYear), List(Of Int32))
    Else
        list = New List(Of Int32)
        data.Add(strYear, list)
    End If
    list.Add(strData)
Next row
```

Comment: please check my code, each time the last value is in the list , I don't know why ?

Comment: Thnaks but what is the new ? I still have the value for the last row in the datatable only !

Comment: Have you used the debugger to inspect the values and to see if it enters the `ContainsKey`?

Comment: Yes is does enter ContainsKey :)

Comment: The new is(among others) that i'm using integers instead of objects. `Equals` and `GethashCode` of `Object` only compare for same references instead of equal values.